# How can I create a Usenet Newsgroup?

Tags: usenet

How can I create a Usenet newsgroup?

I would like to create a Usenet discussion group in the [Big Eight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_8_(Usenet)) hierarchy.  I am not interested in hosting a chat room or internet forum, or creating a newsgroup in alt.*.

I know how to read Usenet and I use a news server that I am happy with.

Comment: @Richard - You could delete the question - But there really is no need. It is a good question, just started out wrong. Also Big Seven was renamed to Big 8 - But I guess you knew that already :)

Comment: @Diago, I'd still like to delete the question.  I tried but I can't.    I guess they added a talk.* hierarchy, making it Big Eight, but it is the Usenet equivalent to Community Wiki, and I don't read it.

Comment: @Richard. Looking at the upvotes keeping it open was a better decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your comments into consideration, and the lack of information on the Big 7, this is what I can find regarding creating a newsgroup in the Big 8.

> Before a new Big 8 newsgroup can be created, an RFD (Request For Discussion) must be posted into the newsgroup news.announce.newgroups, which is then discussed in news.groups.proposals. Once the proposal has been formalized with a name, description, charter, the Big-8 Management Board will vote on whether to create the group. If the proposal is approved by the Big-8 Management Board, the group is created. Groups are removed in a similar manner.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet_newsgroup)

There is a fairly recent article [here](http://help.unc.edu/644) that takes you through the steps for creating one. To be honest it seems quite complex, however it may just be a perception and it really is a lot easier to get it approved.

Answer (score 9):

[Here](http://www.savetz.com/yic/YIC05FI_26.html) is some information you may find useful.

Comment: Is that information still relevant? It seems rather old; I've also found another article (on the first page of results from Google) that was dating back to 1999 about this subject.

Comment: In case you hadn't noticed, Usenet hasn't really moved on from 1999 ;)

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for a [News / NNTP protocol Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_server). I cannot recommend any over any others, but there is a [list available here](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Software/Internet/Servers/Usenet/) (also contains a few clients)

Comment: @Will - Want to look at adjusting your answer now?

Comment: Shall I just delete my response? the only thing I would post would be a duplicate of paul.lydon's link

Comment: @Will - I wouldn't. It's a valid answer and considering that the Big 8 seems complex, still a viable option.